# Copy files from azure web app to Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service

I have files in Azure Web App that I need to copy to a container in my Azure Storage Account.

I previously saved images in the website in a folder within the web-app. Now, I need to separate concern and store them in Azure storage account. I have managed to write code to store new images to the storage account. I need to copy the already existing files to the storage account. How do I achieve this?

*Any insight to the solution is highly appreciated*

Comment: Can you not connect to your website instance by FTP and download the files on your local computer? Once you have them on your local computer, you should be able to upload them in blob storage.

Comment: This helped. Thanks Gaurav

Comment: What method you use to upload at last?

Comment: I used Filezilla to connect to the webapp via FTP, downloaded the images and uploaded them using Azure portal to the container in the storage account

Comment: I thought your company would not allow ftp so I didn't provide that method. I just provided the code, and now I have updated my answer. Can you [mark it as an answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JRjz.png) to end this question? Maybe you can use the method mentioned in my original answer when ftp is not allowed.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

If FTP is allowed. Download and upload images manually is also a method.(Just get the host name and the password is ok.)

[image]

[image]

**Original Answer:**

You can use the code like below:

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxxx");
            var myClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = myClient.GetContainerReference("images");
            var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("grass.jpg");
            blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(xxx);
```

This is the offcial doc of how to download:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#download-blobs

And this is the offcial doc of how to upload:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#upload-blobs-to-a-container

Hope it helps.:)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly from azure portal, without downloading them

1. Login to Azure portal
2. Goto Kudu console (advanced tools menu on the left) and then power shell from there
3. Run AzCopy like

   .\AzCopy /Source:c:\home\site\wwwroot\files_to_move /Dest:"https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/my_container/destination_folder" /S /Y /DestKey:Storage_Account_Key

if you are not able to find AzCopy, then it may be in c:\devtools\azcopy and you can run the command from there.... and booom :)